# WPF XML data binding showing only one item

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, xpath

I have a WPF application with a ListBox which I am trying to bind to an embedded xml file (Named "ServerList.XML", located in a folder named "Data" in my "SQLExecutor" solution. I want the XML to be embedded in the final *.exe) and I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Or rather it only shows a single item from the XML.
I've read on [binding xml using xmldataprovider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-xml-data-using-an-xmldataprovider-and-xpath-queries) and tested different `XPath` variables but to no avail.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Servers xmlns="">
  <Server>
    <Address>10.0.100.43</Address>
    <Authentication>Windows Authentication</Authentication>
    <UserName></UserName>
    <Password></Password>
  </Server>
  <Server>
    <Address>10.0.100.45</Address>
    <Authentication>Windows Authentication</Authentication>
    <UserName></UserName>
    <Password></Password>
  </Server>
</Servers>
```

and my XAML

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxServers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ServerData" Source="/Data/ServerList.xml" XPath="Servers/Server"/>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource ServerData}" XPath="Address"/>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    </ListBox>
```

I've placed the empty namespace in the XML, set the XML `Build Action` to `Content`, tried also with `Resource` and `Embedded Resource`. I used to have troubles with the databinding, itself, but I've hit the correct `URI`, so now I get a databinding but only the first item is shown from the XML:

[image: Runtime]

I have tried all variations of the `URI` and `Build Action` that I know of.
Namely:

- /Data/ServerList.xml
- Data/ServerList.xml
- ServerList.xml
- Resource/ServerList.xml
- Resource/Data/ServerList.xml
- Resource/Other/ServerList.xml
- /Resource/ServerList.xml
- /Resource/Data/ServerList.xml
- /Resource/Other/ServerList.xml
- pack://application:,,,/Data/ServerList.xml
- pack://application:,,,/Other/ServerList.xml
- /pack://application:,,,/Data/ServerList.xml
- /pack://application:,,,/Other/ServerList.xml
- /pack://application:,,,/SQLExecutor;component/ServerList.xml
- /pack://application:,,,/SQLExecutor;component/Data/ServerList.xml
- /pack://application:,,,/SQLExecutor;component/Other/ServerList.xml
- SQLExecutor;component/ServerList.xml
- SQLExecutor;component/Data/ServerList.xml
- SQLExecutor;component/Other/ServerList.xml
- /SQLExecutor;component/ServerList.xml
- /SQLExecutor;component/Data/ServerList.xml
- /SQLExecutor;component/Other/ServerList.xml
- Build Action Content
- Build Action Resource
- Build Action Embedded Resouce
  I've tried all of the combinations and variations of the two above.

Comment: Put the XML file in a project folder named `Data`, not in a solution folder. Then `Source="Data/ServerList.xml"` works with Build Action `Resource`.

Comment: @Clemens, sorry should have mentioned I want it to be embedded in the *.exe

Comment: That's what happens with Build Action Resource. It will create an "assembly resource".

Comment: @Clemens, oh, so you mean not only I need to include it in the solution (or maybe I don't need to put it in the solution at all) but also put it physically on the hard drive in the project folder?

Comment: Project folder is a folder in a Visual Studio project, not in a VS Solution. The folder is however mandatory, you could as well put the file in the project root, in which case its Uri would just be the file name. "physically on the hard drive", not sure what you mean. All files in a VS project are stored somewhere.

Comment: @Clemens, I thought you could add a file to your solution and VS would be smart enough to use it, without you having to manually put it in the project folder, as well. That is why I was confused. EDIT: just checked, the file is already in said folder.

Comment: Adding it to a solution is something different than adding it to a project. You need it to be **only** in a project, **not** in the solution. What's so difficult about that? A project is compiled to an assembly, hence an assembly resource must be part of the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155671/discussion-between-mathgenius-and-clemens).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155672/discussion-between-mathgenius-and-clemens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be selecting a single element with the `XmlDataProvider`'s `XPath`.

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="ServerData" Source="/Data/ServerList.xml" XPath="/Servers" />
```

Then modify your `Binding` to select each `Server` elements' `Address`:

```
<Binding Source="{StaticResource ServerData}" XPath="Server/Address" />
```

This way it will select all the items, not just the first one.

Comment: You should change the `Binding`'s `XPath` to `Server` instead of `/Server`. You're searching for items that are in the root of the XML document and named `Server`. There are no items like that in the XML document, even though you prefiltered with the `XmlDataProvider` (that doesn't give you a new XML document).

Comment: Thanks, that helped but it also turns out it is case-sensitive and I have missed a capital letter. I deleted my comment after fixing it. :)